# Excel VBA: Toggle rows hide/unhide when image clicked

Tags: excel, image, vba

I am brand new to VBA and have an image which i want to assign a macro to so that when the user clicks it, it unhides a range of rows, and when th user clicks it again, it hides the rows.

My image:

Image1.jpg

I have assigned the following maco to this image:

```
Sub sbHidingUnHideRows()
'To Hide Rows 22 to 25
Rows("9:14").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

This unhides my rows when the user clicks the image. But how can i make the rows hide again on the second click? Like a toggle button?

Here's what i've tried:

```
Sub sbHidingUnHideRows()
'To Hide Rows 22 to 25
Rows("9:14").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
Rows("9:14").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

Please can someone show me where i'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Sub sbHidingUnHideRows()
    If Rows("22:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        Rows("22:25").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("22:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End Sub
```